# Boost deserialisation issue : Input Stream Error at runtime (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost, stream

I've serialised a map fine

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> userandPass; 
saveData< std::map<std::string, std::string> >("userandPassBackup.txt", userandPass); // have removed &. why is this needed. i want to pass by reference
```

using the function

```
template <typename SaveClass>
void saveData(const std::string filename, SaveClass& c)
{
// File to be written to
boost::filesystem::remove(boost::filesystem::current_path() / 
filename);
boost::filesystem::path myFile = boost::filesystem::current_path() / 
filename;
// Declare an output file stream ofs that writes serialises to our 
//backup file.
boost::filesystem::ofstream ofs(myFile.native());
// Declare archive ta that will use our output file stream
boost::archive::text_oarchive ta(ofs);
// Write to file
ta << c;
// How many records have been archived?
std::cout << c.size() << " records from have been successfully backed 
up to " << myFile << "\n";
}
```

Deserialising (loading) however, fails, using:

```
loadData< std::map<std::string, std::string> >("userandPassBackup.txt", userandPass);
```

where the function is:

```
template <typename LoadClass>
void loadData(const std::string filename, LoadClass& c)
{
// File to be written to
boost::filesystem::remove(boost::filesystem::current_path() / 
filename);
boost::filesystem::path myFile = boost::filesystem::current_path() / 
filename;
// Declare an output file stream ofs that writes serialises to our 
//backup file.
boost::filesystem::ifstream ifs(myFile.native());
// Declare archive ta that will use our output file stream
boost::archive::text_iarchive ta(ifs);
// Write to file
ta >> c;
// How many records have been archived?
std::cout << c.size() << " records from have been successfully backed 
up to " << myFile << "\n";
}
```

My project compiles, but when I run it, I get the following error concerning the input stream:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error
Abort trap: 6

I don't see why this is happening. Would anyone be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you copypasted `loadData` body from `saveData`. You delete file that you are trying to load as a first step by calling `boost::filesystem::remove`.

Comment: Of course I did. Silly mistake! Thanks a million for your help. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

@VTT got the biggest bug.

Here's my free code review:

- you don't need boost::filesystem to `std::remove(filename)`
- instead of `currentdir / filename` you should do [`boost::filesystem::make_absolute`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#absolute)
- that is already default behaviour
- you should **not** use `native()` since you can pass the path
- the argument to `saveData` can be `const&`
- Do not explicitly pass template arguments: function calls do template argument *deduction*.
- Never mind that your comments are very redundant.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b5560752c528f82)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename SaveClass>
void saveData(const std::string filename, SaveClass const& c)
{
    std::remove(filename.c_str());
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ta(ofs);

    ta << c;
}

template <typename LoadClass>
void loadData(const std::string filename, LoadClass& c)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ta(ifs);
    ta >> c;
}

int main() {
    std::string filename = "userandPassBackup.txt";
    {
        std::map<std::string, std::string> userandPass {
            { "John", "pa$$w0rd" },
            { "Jane", "welcome01" } };
        saveData(filename, userandPass);

        std::cout << userandPass.size() << " records from have been successfully backed up to " << filename << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::map<std::string, std::string> userandPass;
        loadData(filename, userandPass);

        std::cout << userandPass.size() << " records from have been successfully restored from " << filename << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
2 records from have been successfully backed up to userandPassBackup.txt
2 records from have been successfully restored from userandPassBackup.txt
```